# Как получить объект из data атрибута?

Tags: javascript

Почему когда вывожу первый раз `console.log();`, атрибут возвращает строку, а не объект?
А если установить через JS данный атрибут, то возвращает уже объект?
Как изначально получить объект?

```js
var data = JSON.parse( $('.js-block-obj').data('info') );
$('.js-block-obj').on('click', function() {
  console.log( data);

$( ".js-block-obj" ).data( "info", { b: 100, s: 0 } );

console.log( data );
})
```

```css
.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2rem auto 0;
  border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block js-block-obj" data-info="{&quot;b&quot;: 10, &quot;s&quot;: 1}"></div>
```

`JSON.parse` не работает, выдает ошибку:

> Unexpected token b in JSON at position 2

Comment: Двоеточие и кавычки пропустили

Comment: @tutankhamun, двоеточие исправил, ошибка сохранилась. Где пропустил кавычки?

Comment: `data-info="{&quot;b&quot;: 10, &quot;s&quot;: 1}"` в JSON обязательно требуется брать в кавычки ключи полей объектов

Comment: Ээх. Уберите `JSON.parse()`. `jQuery.data()` сам разбирает JSON

Answer (score 1):

Если в атрибуте валидный JSON, то jQuery сам возвратит Вам объект

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var data = $('.js-block-obj').data('info');
  $('.js-block-obj').on('click', function() {
    console.log(data);

    $(".js-block-obj").data("info", {
      b: 100,
      s: 0
    });

    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="block js-block-obj" data-info='{&quot;b&quot;: 10, &quot;s&quot;: 1}'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Рекомендуется вместо `$(document).ready()` использовать `$()`

Comment: @tutankhamun Спасибо. Не знал

Answer (score 1):

1. Никак. data-атрибуты могут содержать только строки.
2. Если нужно сохранять объект, то его надо сериализовать в строку.
   Например, перед сохранением делать `JSON.stringify`, а после чтения `JSON.parse`.
3. Получить строку можно через `elem.dataset.attrName` для `data-attr-name="..."`.
4. Если браузер старый, то вместо dataset'а надо использовать `getAttribute`.
5. Если есть jQuery, то функцией `data` можно сохранять что угодно.
6. Dom-элементу можно как и любому другому объекту приделать собственные свойства, не связанные с атрибутами.